# error in ./node_modules/@mui/utils/esm/exactProp.js Module parse failed: Unexpected token (10:4)

Tags: reactjs, mui

error  in ./node_modules/@mui/utils/esm/exactProp.js

```
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (10:4)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|   }
|   return {
|     ...propTypes,
|     [specialProperty]: props => {
|       const unsupportedProps = Object.keys(props).filter(prop => !propTypes.hasOwnProperty(prop));

 @ ./node_modules/@mui/utils/esm/index.js 6:0-51
 @ ./node_modules/@mui/material/Button/buttonClasses.js
 @ ./node_modules/@mui/material/Button/index.js
```

Tengo este error, a mis compañeros no les genera error pero a mi si, ya puse en la consola yarn add @mui/material @mui/styled-engine-sc styled-components
pero aun asi me sigue arrojando errores